# Is it acceptable to miss out joining words (e.g. who, which)?

Tags: grammar

My kids were singing a song this morning:

> "There was a farmer had a dog and Bingo was his name, oh."

And it occurred to me the word "who" had been omitted to make it scan. In normal speech, you would more usually say:

> "There was a farmer **who** had a dog..."

Is it ever acceptable to miss out "joining" words like "who", "which" or "that" in sentences such as these?

Comment: **1.** Critique of lyrics is a no-no on ELU. **2.** Read that on **separate lines:** "There was a farmer\ had a dog\ and Bingo was his name,\ oh," and it all makes sense. That's how lyrics, ditties are.

Comment: @Kris **1.** I'm not critiquing the song itself. I'm saying that it made me wonder about the question of whether that grammar would be acceptable, and realised I didn't know. **2.** I don't see how that makes it make sense.

Comment: @Urbycoz: absolutely right on. That's the reason, all right. The rhythm doesn't allow for an extra syllable, so the _who/that_ subject relative pronoun got deleted, as the predictable part. Normally you can't delete a relative pronoun if it's the subject (as this is); but there are sociolects where it's not uncommon.

Comment: @John: Structurally/syntactically, I can't really see much difference between OP's example and *"This is a question [**that**] I can't answer"*, where the optional "that" just looks like another *subject relative pronoun* to me. And although I don't *necessarily* trust it, Google Books tells me there are three times as many instances of my alternative *without* "that" as there are with it. How does that square with "Normally you can't delete a relative pronoun if it's the subject"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The difference is easy. In _This is a question (that/which) I couldn't answer,_ the relative pronoun is **not** the subject of the relative clause, and therefore it **can** be deleted. In _This is a question that/which appears on the exam,_ the relative pronoun **is** the subject of the relative clause, and therefore **can't** be deleted. As I stated in my comment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about song lyrics.

Comment: @Kris I'm not critiquing the song itself. I'm saying that it made me wonder about the question of whether that grammar would be acceptable, and realised I didn't know.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingo_(folk_song)), the modern version of the song is:

> **"There Was a Farmer Who Had a Dog"**.
>
> - It  is an English language children's song of obscure origin. In most modern forms, the song involves spelling the name of a dog (Bingo) , and with increasing letters replaced with handclaps on each repetition.

**"There was a farmer had a dog"** (the original and still used title), isn't proper grammar, but it isn't meant to be. It's meant to follow the meter of the music.

This is also an old-fashioned structure you'll hear or see in old books, and it was often the way people of the lower classes spoke. For example, in the Shakespeare play [Henry IV](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/1henryiv/full.html), Prince Henry says, "*there is a devil haunts thee in the likeness of an old fat man,*" notably missing the joining word between "devil" and "haunts."

Comment: I think it's unfortunate that they're trying to change the song. The grammatically correct version sounds stupid. Well answered in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The song could be sung with "who" in it. 
There was a farmer "whohad" a dog. Try singing the words Who & Had together, it will work.

Comment: The question isn't about changing the song, but if you did want to add "who" to the lyrics it would sound better to change the "er" of "farmer" to a sixteenth note and add "who" as a sixteenth note, leaving "had" unchanged on the third beat where it belongs. It sounds better without "who" though.

Answer (score 0):

Non-native English speaker wonders:
Why couldn't it be --
"There was -> [**a farmer had a dog** and Bingo was his name-o]", similar to "there was [a thing]", where it is fine to omit joining words, like *who* or *that*?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).